# Как удалить пуш firebase

Tags: firebase, уведомления, push-уведомления, push

Что нужно отправить в firebase, чтобы удалить определенный пуш,если отправить badge:0 то стираются все пуши

Comment: web, android, ios?

Comment: @AntonKomyshan backend -> firebase